# Get URL instead of image when trying to show it in modal window with jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, modal-dialog

I'm having a newbie problem when trying to display an image in a modal popup with jQuery.
I'm using the following code:

```
function showBlogImage(image, title)
{
   var img_url = '/images/public/admins/' + image;
   $('#blog-image-modal').html(img_url);
   if(!$("#blog-image-modal").dialog( "isOpen" )){
   $('#blog-image-modal').dialog("open");
   }
   return false;
}
```

The code sort of works in as far as the modal does actually pop up, only it does display the image's URL instead of the image itself ...
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function showBlogImage(image, title)
{
   var img_url = '/images/public/admins/' + image;
   $('#blog-image-modal').html('<img src="' + img_url + '" alt="' + title + '" />');
   if(!$("#blog-image-modal").dialog( "isOpen" )){
   $('#blog-image-modal').dialog("open");
   }
   return false;
}
```

You need to tell the browser it's an image, otherwise it'll just think it's a piece of text.

Comment: Not sure why but I prefer creating an object and appending it rather than setting it via the `.html()` method. I guess  it's easy to get confused with the single/double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the image rather than just appending the URL of the image and then append it to the modal window.

**Here's the code**

```
function showBlogImage(image, title)
{
   var img_url = '/images/public/admins/' + image;
   var $img = $("<img />").attr("src", img_url).attr("alt", title); // Create an image element and set it's src and alt attributes. This can be shortened with attr({src: im_url, alt: title}); instead of double .attr methods.
   $('#blog-image-modal').append($img);
   if(!$("#blog-image-modal").dialog( "isOpen" )){
   $('#blog-image-modal').dialog("open");
   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
$('#blog-image-modal').html(img_url);
```

To this:

```
$('#blog-image-modal').append($("<img>").attr({ src: img_url }));
```